# Conversion of fractional part of a hexadecimal number to binary

Tags: arithmetic, binary, base-conversion

The Number is given as : (C012.25)Hexadecimal
I have to convert it into octal .
So I converted it into Binary First and got the result as : **1100000000010010.01000000**
*(Since each bit in hexadecimal represents 4 bit in binary so C=1100,0=0000,1=0001,2=0010 and for 0.25=.01000000 )*
The Solution mentions the Binary conversion as **1100000000010010.00100101**

Please guide me about the what was done wrong !
Also if I got the binary representation...How can I convert the binary no's fractional part (0.00100101) into octal .

Comment: (0.25) in Hex is  0010 0101 as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Can you guide what are the steps involved in finding the correct answer

Comment: every number in Hexa(0 to F)  is equivalent to its binary equivalent.   so 1 is 0010, 2 is 0010, 3 is 0011 ....7 is 0111, 8 is 1000, ...A(10) is 1010, B is 1011, E(14) is 1110 and F(15) is 1111. If a number is in Hexa, then all you have to do is replace every hexa digit( total 16) with its equivalent binary.

Comment: Okey Thanks I got that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to convert the fractional part from hexadecimal to binary:
$$
(0.25)_{16} = \frac{2}{16} + \frac{5}{16^2} =
\frac{0 \cdot 8 + 0 \cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 2 + 0 \cdot 1}{16} +
\frac{0 \cdot 8 + 1 \cdot 4 + 0 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 1}{16^2} = \\
\frac{0}{2} + \frac{0}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{0}{16} + \frac{0}{32} + \frac{1}{64} + \frac{0}{128} + \frac{1}{256} = (0.00100101)_2
$$
As you can see, we simply replace $2$ with its base 2 representation, and then adjoin the base 2 representation of $5$. I included this calculation to show *why* this works.

Note also that $(0.25)_{16} \neq 1/4$.

Comment: Thanks Great Help !...I learnt it !